# Magento 2: How to create custom ui_component form to submit data by ajax

Tags: magento2, ajax, uicomponent, fatal-error

I tried to create a custom ui_component form to submit data by ajax on the frontend. But it didn't appear.

This is the error I got.

> Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null in /var/www/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php on line 0

This is my ui-component form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form.rentalshipping_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form.rentalshipping_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form</item>
        </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="rentalshipping_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model\RentalShippingFromProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">rentalshipping_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="employee_details">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Details</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="employee_id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Id</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Name</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_salary">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Salary</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_salary</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="employee_address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Employee Address</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">employee</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">employee_address</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This is my dataprovider class:

```
namespace SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Model;

class RentalShippingFromProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null
     */
    protected $_product = null;

    /**
     * @var \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig
     */
    protected $_shipmentConfig;

    /**
     * @var TurnoverByShipment
     */
    protected $_rshippingModel;

    /**
     * RentalShippingFromProvider constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig
     * @param TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \SalesIgniter\RentalShipping\Helper\ShipmentConfig $shipmentConfig,
        TurnoverByShipment $rshippingModel,
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_shipmentConfig = $shipmentConfig;
        $this->_rshippingModel = $rshippingModel;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('cfl');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('cfl'); //cfl Frontend route name;
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
```

**Please add two data provider file in your module :**
**one path :** `model/DataProvider`
and second `model/Faq/DataProvider` //here faq is my module name.
and this file in `model/Faq/DataProvider`

**model/DataProvide :**

```
namespace Cwiser\Faq\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\Reporting;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider
{

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param Reporting $reporting
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
     * @param RequestInterface $request
     * @param FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        Reporting $reporting,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        RequestInterface $request,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $name,
            $primaryFieldName,
            $requestFieldName,
            $reporting,
            $searchCriteriaBuilder,
            $request,
            $filterBuilder,
            $meta,
            $data
        );
    }

    protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
    {
        parent::prepareUpdateUrl();
    }
}
```

///
**model/Faq/DataProvider:**

```
namespace Cwiser\Faq\Model\Faq;

use Cwiser\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\Faq\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;

class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    protected $dataPersistor;

    protected $loadedData;
    protected $collection;


    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DataPersistorInterface $dataPersistor,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->dataPersistor = $dataPersistor;
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        foreach ($items as $model) {
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
        }
        $data = $this->dataPersistor->get('cfl');

        if (!empty($data)) {
            $model = $this->collection->getNewEmptyItem();
            $model->setData($data);
            $this->loadedData[$model->getId()] = $model->getData();
            $this->dataPersistor->clear('cfl');
        }

        return $this->loadedData;
    }
}
```